# what is the cause of this shading smooth shadow in the plane?

Tags: mesh, vertices, extrude

so I went to mesh and created a plane Rotate it 90 degree on the x axis , went to edit mode extrude using E a bit , and I turned on Auto Smooth than I shadow smooth it , and this is what I got ,,, i tried many things removed the plane do it all over again , applied the scale still the same , any solution? thank you[image]

Edit: I almost forgot sorry , I clicked on the verticies on the side on everyside and I bevel Them

[image]

this is blender file for more details

Comment: Have you checked the normals of the object? - You can turn Face Orientation on in the Viewport Overlays. Share your Blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to add a link so that we can see what's going on.

Comment: Even JohnEason is correct - your Normals are switched, but they are switched all so the result with Normal Outside is similar. Object on your screen is with Auto Smooth > Off (and not checked as you described).

Comment: The cause is that the flat face of your object is an N-gon (a face with more than 4 sides). N-gons make it impossible for 3D softwares to correctly smooth out the normals of the faces (that's what shade smooth does), and so it creates shading issues. To prevent this from happening you can activate auto smooth normals, so it won't try to smooth the normals when the angle between two faces is greater than a set amount, so it won't try to smooth between the flat face and the sides.

Comment: thank you it worked thanks both of u , at some point i did activate the auto smooth but now i activated it again and it worked which is stil confusing i did something wrong probably anyway much appreciated guys , helpful asual

Comment: You are welcomed :) ... in general your question should be marked as duplication, was asked many times, but I can't find any well formulated at the moment ... hm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All shaded as Smooth ...
First and third AutoSmooth disabled ... second and fourth enabled ...
[image]
... the third would look same as the first, both are shaded smoot the only difference is a topology - to avoid bad shading for N-gon face you can *inset* (I) face.

First two Normals - Inside, Last two Normals - Outside
[image]

As mentioned by @AlexandreMarcati ... for Blender it is hard to calculate normals for N-Gons ... for shading and rendering they are internally randomly triangulated ... and that is the source of issue.

[image]